# how to combine forfiles, copy, and @fname?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This command is supposed to copy multiple files from a static source folder into each folder for a set of saved web pages:

```
forfiles /m *.htm /c "cmd /c copy /y _core/*.* @fname_files"
```

However, each call fails with a status of, "The system cannot find the file specified."

If this is tried:

```
forfiles /m *.htm /c "cmd /c copy /y 0x22_core/*.*0x22 @fname_files"
```

the status displayed shows the name of each source file and the same error message.

I've also tried adding `setlocal`/`endlocal` around the call but it still fails.

Searching on the web brought lots of discussions but nothing showing `forfiles`, `cmd`, and copying into a destination directory using `@fname`.

Would someone with deeper knowledge of batch scripting "fix" this line so it works as intended?

Comment: `core/*.*` should be `core\*.*`. Add an `echo` between `cmd /c` and `copy /y` to see, what you actually try to execute.

Comment: The `FORFILES` variables are output quote surrounded.  I assume this is causing problems with the way you want to use that variable as well. What you are attempting to do doesn't make any sense to me, so maybe if you explain what you are attempting to do we can provide a better solution.  I am not sure why you are using `FORFILES` in the first place.  There is no need to.  A simple `FOR` command would get you a list of htm files.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do :

1)You might be getting "The system cannot find the file specified." because the directory **_core** is not in the same directory as the ***.htm** files

2)In order to copy the *.htm files into each  @fname_files folder, you must create the folder first. Here is the command line with mkdir added :

```
forfiles /m *.htm /c "cmd /c mkdir @fname_files & copy /y _core\*.* @fname_files"
```